# matlab adding a string to each element of a numeric vector

Tags: string, matlab, concatenation

I need to switch between a vector of numerics and a vector of strings:

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 5]
b = {'xx1', 'xx2', 'xx3', 'xx4'}
```

I tried `strcat('XX', num2str(a))`, but it returns `XX1 2 3 4 5`, which is not what I want. Can someone tell me how to create `b` from `a` and how to create `a` from `b`? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for loops or `cellfun`. Let

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 15];
b = {'xx1', 'xx2', 'xx4', 'xx15'};
```

### From `b` to `a`

Convert `a` to a cell array of strings using [`num2str`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) with format specifier `'%-i'` to exploit the fact that [`cellstr`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html) ignores trailing spaces; and after using the latter concatenate via [`strcat`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html):

```
b_from_a = strcat('xx', cellstr(num2str(a(:), '%-i'))).';
```

### From `a` to `b`

Delete `xx` from each string using [`strrep`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html), then apply [`str2double`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html):

```
a_from_b = str2double(strrep(b, 'xx', ''));
```

Answer (score 2):

**B FROM A**

There is an undocumented Matlab function that I love to use and works perfectly in this kind of situations: `sprintfc`. It's lightning-fast and allows to convert numerical vectors into cell vectors of characters arrays using a custom format:

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 5];
b = sprintfc('xx%d',a)

b =
    1×4 cell array
    'xx1'   'xx2'   'xx4'   'xx5'
```

**A FROM B**

This is pretty simple using a replacement:

```
b = {'xx1', 'xx2', 'xx3', 'xx4'};
a = str2double(strrep(b,'xx',''))

a =
    1     2     3     4
```

Comment: In 16b the compose function was added which is a whole lot like sprintfc but documented.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

without loop you can using `cellfun`:

```
xxs = cell(1,4);
xxs(:) = 'XX';
q = cell(1,4); q{1}=1;q{2}=2;q{3}=4;q{4}=5;
result = cellfun(@(x,i) strcat(x, num2str(i)), xxs,q, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

## Solution 2

Using loop:

```
a = [1 2 4 5];
result = cell(1,length(a));
for i = 1:length(a)
     result{i} = strcat('XX',num2str(a(i)));
end
```

Comment: thanks. i was hoping to find some non-loop way. after a lot of internet searching, apparently strcat('XX', string(a)) would work for matlab 2016 onwards. unfortunately mine is 2015... so i guess i'll stick to loops

Comment: just for the reference in case someone ends up on this page: the code doesnt work for me either (maybe its the matlab 2015 issue again), i have to use strcat('XX',num2str(a(i))) instead

Comment: @ian_chan you can find a solution without loop too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open using a loop instead of vectorized functions, it could be done fairly easily. For example:

```
clc; clear;

a = [1, 2, 4, 5];
for i = 1:length(a)
    b{i} = strcat('XX', num2str(a(i)));
end
b
```

returns

```
b =

  1×4 cell array

{'XX1'}    {'XX2'}    {'XX4'}    {'XX5'}
```

If you want to go the other way, you could do this.

```
for i = 1:length(b)
    c(i) = str2double(b{i}(3:end));
end
c
```

which returns

```
c =

     1     2     4     5
```

It's worth noting here that better code would [pre-allocate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) both `b` and `c`.

Comment: thanks. i was hoping to find some non-loop way. after a lot of internet searching, apparently strcat('XX', string(a)) would work for matlab 2016 onwards. unfortunately mine is 2015... so i guess i'll stick to loops

Answer (score 0):

In 16b MATLAB added a new string class and in 17a you can construct a string from double quotes. Using string,

```
"xx" + a
```

would give you the desired answer. Here is a performance comparison of string against the other solutions:

```
>> profFunc
matlabbit solution: 0.29956
Luis Mendo solution: 15.2378
OmG solution 1: 41.0055
OmG solution 2: 29.1976
Tommaso Belluzzo solution: 1.3574


function  profFunc

    a = [1, 2, 4, 5];

    n = 1E5;

    tic;
    for i = 1:n
        ans = "xx" + a;
    end
    disp("matlabbit solution: " + toc);

    tic;
    for i = 1:n
        ans = strcat('xx', cellstr(num2str(a(:), '%-i'))).';
    end
    disp("Luis Mendo solution: " + toc);

    tic;
    for i = 1:n
        xxs = cell(1,4);
        xxs(:) = {'XX'};
        q = cell(1,4); q{1}=1;q{2}=2;q{3}=4;q{4}=5;
        ans = cellfun(@(x,i) strcat(x, num2str(i)), xxs,q, 'UniformOutput', false);
    end
    disp("OmG solution 1: " + toc);

    tic;
    for i = 1:n
        ans = cell(1,length(a));
        for i = 1:length(a)
             ans{i} = strcat('XX',num2str(a(i)));
        end 
    end
    disp("OmG solution 2: " + toc);

    tic;
    for i = 1:n
        ans = sprintfc('xx%d',a);
    end
    disp("Tommaso Belluzzo solution: " + toc);
end
```